# How to not remove certain files with Inno Setup installer and uninstaller

Tags: installation, inno-setup

I am creating an installer using Inno Setup. Below is my code.

In my code, I save the configuration files in `{userappdata}\testApp\settingFiles`.

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\hold\kivyTest\settingFiles\*"; \
    DestDir: "{userappdata}\testApp\settingFiles"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs
```

I don't want to delete `{userappdata}\testApp\settingFiles` once the user has set up.

I do not want to delete this folder when the uninstaller is run.

Also, I don't want to overwrite this folder when the installer is run.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are looking for [`onlyifdoesntexist`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=onlyifdoesntexist) and [`uninsneveruninstall` flags](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=filessection&anchor=uninsneveruninstall).

```
[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\taichi\Documents\hold\kivyTest\settingFiles\*"; \
    DestDir: "{userappdata}\testApp\settingFiles"; \
    Flags: ignoreversion recursesubdirs createallsubdirs \
           onlyifdoesntexist uninsneveruninstall
```